# Java: Trying to print out data contents of a List<Integer>, but only get pointer address

Tags: java, list, arraylist

```
public static void printFib(List<Integer> fib){
    JTextArea text = new JTextArea();
    for(Iterator<Integer> it = fib.iterator(); it.hasNext(); it.next() ){
        text.append(it.toString());
        text.append("\n");
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,text);
}
```

How can I modify this to have it actually print the data contents and not the pointer address?

Comment: Try `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, text.getText());`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you really need an interator?

```
for (Integer i : fib)
{
    text.append(i.toString());
    text.append("\n");
}
```

If for some reason you need an iterator for something else, then you use it as:

```
Iterator<Integer> it = fib.iterator();
while (it.hasNext())
{
    text.append(it.next().toString());
    text.append("\n");
}
```

**Edit:** To summarize comments below; Rather than getting the `Integer` the iterator contained via `it.next()`, The OP was calling the iterator's `toString()` method and receiving a `String` containing the hex representation of the iterator's hash code.

Comment: Apparently not. I was unaware that this was possible. It doesn't change my error message tough. This results in "The method append(String) in the type JTextArea is not applicable for the arguments (Integer)"

Comment: @user1191205 You need to use `i.toString()`.

Comment: Odd I guess it doesn't call `toString()` implicitly - editing

Comment: The pattern in implementation of iterator by OP is better then your advise. It is of course obsolete, after for each loop was introduced in Java. But in the case that we need to to use the iterator it should be done like OP wrote. Beside that your answer assume that OP know what for each loop is, i think that if he would be aware of it, it would be used.

Comment: @user1191205 - for "for-each" loop was added in Java 6. it's handy :)

Comment: @DaveNewton Thank you. I used this earlier, but that resulted in the pointer address being printed instead of the data. What can I read up on to learn the difference between what I originally did and what Brian did? EDIT: Aha, so that's the syntax for for each in Java. I didn't know this was a thing in Java now :) Thanks!

Comment: @Vash - Yeah, I guess those guys at Sun got it wrong when they wrote the documentation on how to use iterators back in the day ... http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Collections/Using/index.html#iterators

Comment: @user1191205 - in your example you're calling the `toString()` method of the *iterator* rather than the thing the iterator contains (which you retrieve with its `next()` method). This results in you getting a String containing the hex representation of the hashcode of the iterator.

Comment: @user1191205 As Brian says, you're doing something different--I was referring to Brian's code.

Comment: @brian-roach - Thank you for your quick assistance. I've read myself blind on this for over two hours :p Bad choice of Google search arguments I guess.

Comment: @BrianRoach, as I feel that your answer is a little bit sarcastic. I will not try to, explain why using while is not best choice for iterators. You should just read Efficient Java by Joshua Bloch, especially chapter 8, item 45 - Minimize the scope of local variables.

Comment: @Vash - and you should perhaps understand the actual problem before posting a completely wrong answer, nitpicking on a correct answer, downvoting it, then altering your answer to match everyone else's. Or not. Whatever floats your boat :)

Comment: My down vote, was because pass JTextArea as message i do not expect that the content of it will be printed. And that was also base of my answer. Your assumption that I have altered my answer to match everyone else is stupid. Because every one else in that time IMHO was focusing on the iteration issue, not that passing JTextArea instance ti JoptionPane as message will still print memory address, in addition the edit is about code improvement regarding syntax and class usage. So your answer is correct only if passing JTextArea instance is fine to print content, if so i will remove down vote.

Comment: PS. i wrote all that, not to establish who have right, because we both probably do in some way. I was only thrilled, that giving a advice about code style i would be considered as pure evil. I totally do not follow why you are so closed for words of comment but that is really childish from you side.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing it like that anyway?

```
for (Integer i : fib) {
    text.append(i.toString());
    text.append("\n");
}
```

Anyway, you're appending `it` (not `it.next()`). You're printing the iterator, not what's being iterated.

---

If I were doing it I'd probably write the method like this; YMMV:

```
public static void printFib(List<Integer> fib){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (Integer i : fib) {
        sb.append(i).append("\n");
    }

    JTextArea text = new JTextArea(sb.toString());
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, text);
}
```

Actually, I'd probably do it like this, but they make special little buses for people like me:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> fib = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
    display(buildFibOutput(fib));
}

private static void display(String s){
    JTextArea text = new JTextArea(s);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, text);
}

private static String buildFibOutput(List<Integer> fib) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (Integer i : fib) {
        sb.append(i).append("\n");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: If the are creating buses, that mean that you are not alone.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to use an iterator, you need to get the `next` value and print that, not the iterator itslef, which you are doing.  Something like

```
//create an iterator, then
while (it.hasNext()) {
   text.append(it.next());
   ...
}
```

While you can use a for loop, I think a while loop is probably simpler to understand in the context...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public static void printFib(List<Integer> fib){
    JTextArea text = new JTextArea();
    for(Integer it : fib){
        text.append(it.toString());
        text.append("\n");
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,text);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

your problem is that `text` is JTextArea instance. After passing it to `JOptionPane.showMessageDialo(null,text);` over text is called method `toString()`, which is delivered by Object super type. To solve this problem, you need to pass to that method the content of that `text` instance. To do that just call method `getText()`, and should work.

In addition to improve your code:

I no aware how method `append`, works but a good practice is to use `StringBuilder` class to reduce the operation over immutable `String` objects. As the are immutable, when you need a concatenation of those you are really creating new one object, so each pass of loop will create new object. Another thing is that you are using obsolete approach, for `List` iteration. Since [foreach loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) has been introduced in Java, it should be used instead that for pattern you have implemented. The for each loop can be used over all elements, that implements interface [Iterable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html), so improved version of your code would look like:

```
public static <T> void print(Iterable<T> iterable){

    if(iterator == null) { //We throw an exception if method can not operater
       throw new IllegelArgumentException("The argument iterable must not be null".
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for(T element : iterable) { //for each loop
       sb.apppend(String.valueOf(element)); 
       sb.append("\n");
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,sb.toString());
}
```

In addition the [method is generic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html).